# Tizen SDK for Samsung TV Web App throws java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Double

Tags: java, eclipse, tizen, tizen-web-app, tizen-sdk

I am starting to learn how to build Web App for Samsung TVs. I have installed Tizen SDK 2.4.0 Rev4 and Java 8 Updates 74.

I imported existing Tizen Web TV app (tv-2.4) into Tizen IDE on Mac X Yosemite 10.10.5.

When I open Tizen IDE, it throws the following error.

**Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Tizen Web Builder' on project '{ProjectName}'.
java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Double**

If I hit the OK button in the alert dialog, I can continue to develop and view the app using Web Simulator.

However, when I try to view it on TV (Run As -> Tizen Web Application) with the device in the Connection Explorer window selected, the same error gets displayed and nothing happens.

I uninstalled Tizen SDK and reinstalled hoping that would fix it. I also updated Java from Java 8 Updates 73 to Java 8 Updates 74. No luck.

Do you know how can I fix this issue and be able to view the app on TV? The application is just build with HTML and JavaScript. I have no Java code in this project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was caused by the wrong author certificate password. Regenerating the certificates fixed the issue and now I can deploy the app to TV.

Answer (score 1):

With respect to the error:
`Errors occurred during the build. Errors running builder 'Tizen Web Builder' on project '{ProjectName}'. java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Double`

Everyone on my team has the same problem with 2.4 R4.  But this error appears to be innocuous.  The first click to debug/run, builds the project and displays the error.  The second click launches the app without any issues.

This problem does not occur in 2.4 R3, and appears to be corrected in 2.4 R5.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading your IDE to 2.4R6 should solve your problem. Certificates will remain in your computer, but you'll probably need to reset your TV to re-enable the developer mode.